# Gas Cost for setting whitelist addresses on contract

Tags: solidity, gas, nft

I know we all have high gas cost problems with whitelist.
I noticed that there are two approaches to set whitelist addresses on the contract.
I want to know which one costs lower gas.

**[approach 1]**

```
function whitelistUsers(address[] calldata _users) public onlyOwner {
    delete whitelistedAddresses;
    whitelistedAddresses = _users;
  }

function isWhitelisted(address _user) public view returns (bool) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < whitelistedAddresses.length; i++) {
      if (whitelistedAddresses[i] == _user) {
          return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

**[approach2]**

```
function getWhitelistState(address user) public view returns(bool) {
    return whitelistes[user];
  }
  function setWhitelistAddresses(address[] calldata addresses) external onlyOwner {
    for (uint8 i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) 
      whitelisted[addresses[i]] = true;
    whitelistAccessCount += addresses.length;
  }
```

Comment: Did you try executing the functions and measuring the costs yourself? It should be quicker than asking here. There are tools like remix, or plugins for Truffle, Hardhat that evaluate gas costs and show a resume of the costs. It is likely there are similar tools for other frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends on how your contract is used.

E.g. if you have a custom interface and expect that all interactions are done via that interface it is feasible to use the solution proposed by `p0pps`.

When comparing your two approaches then `approach 2` is cheaper in any case.

If we look at setting the whitelist, then storing an array on the blockchain will require to write each element of the array and the length of the array to the blockchain (so n+1 writes). For the mapping approach you need to update the value for each element (so n writes).

For reading the status of the whitelist you need to read exactly 1 storage slot in the mapping approach, while when storing the array you worst case have to read the whole whitelist from storage (so all n elements).

Only downside of the mapping approach is that keeping track of the whitelisted addresses is more tricky as you cannot just return the whole array. An alternative would be to use a linked list: https://hackernoon.com/a-linked-list-implementation-for-ethereum-deep-dive-oy9432pa

A general comment on your code for `approach 2`:

Your `whitelistAccessCount` is not always correct. If you call `setWhitelistAddresses` multiple times and the arrays contain addresses that are already whitelisted, then your count will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be a very expensive white list solution.

Please check out merkle proofs:
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/utilities#verifying_merkle_proofs

Will be much much cheaper.